# How do I remove the horizontal scroll bar from my Navbar

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I'm trying to make a responsive site, in which when the width decreases, my nav-links go out of sight, but there is a ***Horizontal Scroll Bar***, that I want to get rid of. I've viewed other question for this, but none of them helped me. 
Any Suggestions? 
Thank in advance 

HTML

```
    <header class="head">
        <nav class="navbar">

            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">Krishang Sharma</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav-items">
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="crossMenu">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Theme Toggle Switch -->
            <div class="switch">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', serif;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px #1e1e1e;
}

.logo{
    width: 40%;
}

.logo a{
    color: white;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo a:hover{
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #639FAB;
}

.nav-items{
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;   
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-items, li a{
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-items a:hover{
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #639FAB;
}

.crossMenu{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.line1, .line2{
    margin: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    width: 35px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #639FAB;
}

.switch{
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}

.bg{
    height: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.circle{
    right: 5px;
    top: -5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    background: #639FAB;
}

.circleOn{
    background: white;
    right: -35px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.bgOn{
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    background: #639FAB;
}
```

For Lower Resoultion

```
    .nav-items{
        right: 15%;
        position: absolute;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
        transform: translateX(200%);
    }
```

Comment: You must format your question properly. It is really difficult to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `style=` attribute of your navbar.

Comment: Worked for desktop, but when I use the dev tools to check for "phone screens", the scroll bar is present again.

Comment: It would be better if you edit your question and format the code properly.

Comment: @KrishangSharma try changing the position of navbar to `position:fixed` i think it will also disable scroll on dev tools phone screen

Answer (score 0):

Why You have used **transform: translateX(200%);** on **.nav-items** element?. You should remove/add **transform: translateX(0);** on **.nav-items** this element. Then Horizontal Scroll Bar will not show

Comment: I am not able to get what you are saying?! Can you please explain a bit more. Thanks

Comment: Your element has gone outside of the viewport for this **transform: translateX(200%);**. So if You remove this **transform: translateX(200%);** then Scrollbar will not show. If you open developer tools on your web page then you will understand better. Thanks